# Pushing Windows Updates Via Powershell

Tags: powershell, networking, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am trying to install certain windows updates via powershell due to the amount of computers that I need to patch.

I use the following syntax;

```
enter-pssession PCname-PC
```

Once session is connected I use the following;

```
wusa.exe c:\temp\update.msu /quiet /norestart /log:C:\wusa.log
```

The issue at hand, is that nothing happens and I keep getting Access Denied every time. Powershell is ran as admin, local user of the computer is an admin. I have tried running a script that allowed the session to connect as a domain admin, with same results.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Or you can try this: $pc="PC"
`$comm = "cmd /c wusa.exe c:\temp\update.msu /quiet /norestart /log:C:\wusa.log" 

([wmiclass]"\\$pc\root\cimv2:Win32_Process").create($comm)`

Comment: Or you can try to use credentional param: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC1 -Credential contoso\administrator`

Comment: Some versions of Windows block you from writing to the root of the C:\ drive. Try changing /log to another directory.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try your suggestions and update

Answer (score 1):

The [remote use of the Windows Update Agent API is restricted](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2773898/windows-update-standalone-installer-wusa-returns-0x5-error-access-deni). There are several workarounds which revolve around starting the process locally. Either through launching a process through WMI as Vitaly notes in the comments or creating a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will end up copying the update to each PC:

```
$PCs = @()
$Cred = Get-Credential

ForEach ($PC in $PCs)
{
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $PC -Credential $Cred
    Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Temp\Update.msu' -Destination 'C:\Temp\Update.msu' -ToSession $Session -Force
    Enter-PSSession $Session
    & wusa C:\Temp\Update.msu /quiet /norestart /log:C:\Temp\wusa.evtx
    Exit-PSSession
    Remove-PSSession $Session
}
```

One last note: wusa logs in event viewer format (`.evtx`)

Comment: The problem is that wusa.exe can't be run in a remote session. The access denied is not to the file but to the Windows Update API....